# Strange comportment of Show for filling plots

Tags: graphics

Why such a comportment?

Look at those plots

```
 p1 = Plot[PDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], x], {x, -4, 4}, 
  FillingStyle -> LightRed];
 p2 = Plot[PDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], x], {x, -4, -1}, 
  Filling -> Bottom, FillingStyle -> LightYellow];
 p3 = Plot[PDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], x], {x, 1, 4}, 
  Filling -> Bottom, FillingStyle -> LightYellow];
 p4 = Plot[PDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], x], {x, -1, 1}, 
  Filling -> Bottom, FillingStyle -> LightRed];
```

If I ask MA for the following command

```
 Show[p1, p2, p3, p4]
```

it delivers

[image]

If I ask MA for the following command

```
 Show[p4, p2, p3, p1]
```

it now delivers

[image]

In both cases I do not obtain what I was expecting

Comment: I think this is related to the order of precedence for plot range. If you do `Show[p4, p2, p3, p1, PlotRange -> All, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]` then you will get your first graph again. Show inherits the graphics options of the first graphics object in the list. See the documentation for `Show[]` [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Show.html)

Comment: Dunlop is correct. If there is need for further explanation, what output did you expect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Filling` is typically done either up to the bottom of the plot, or to the horizontal axis. The position of either of these (in plot coordinates) depends on the plot range.  Once the filling is created, it becomes static and won't change to adapt to future changes in the plot range (e.g. due to `Show`).  This is why the pink filling doesn't go all the way to the bottom in your first example.

In your case the plot range is automatically determined and differs for the four plots. The solution: Make sure that the object which determines the filling boundary (bottom frame or axis) is at the same position in all four.

I would use `Filling -> Axis` and `AxesOrigin -> {0,0}` in all four `Plot` commands.

Alternatively, use `Filling -> Bottom` and manually set `PlotRange -> {0,0.5}` or similar.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use  `RegionPlot`:

```
pdf[x_] := PDF[NormalDistribution[], x]
Show[RegionPlot[{Abs[x] < 1 && 0 < y < pdf[x], 
   Abs[x] > 1 && 0 < y < pdf[x]}, {x, -4, 4}, {y, 0, 0.4}, 
  PlotStyle -> {LightRed, LightYellow}, BoundaryStyle -> None], 
 Plot[pdf[x], {x, -4, 4}]]
```

[image]